# usbfs: Can I read a USB device's binary object store descriptor (BOS)?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I am able to read device descriptor fields from the usbfs files in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/`.

If a USB device has a Binary Device Object Store (BOS) descriptor, is this stored in the usbfs as well?